# How to call limited data items per page?

Tags: nodes, database, paging

I am using one custom module, which is getting data from the database, with the following code.

```
function rs_get_doors() {
  $doors = array();
  $doors_nids =  db_select('node', 'n')
  $doors_nids = $door_nids->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10);
    ->condition('n.type', 'vivarium_door')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchCol();

  foreach ($doors_nids as $nid) {
    $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node', $nid);
    $doors[$nid] = array(
      'name' => $wrapper->title->value(),
      'fee_nid' => $wrapper->field_fee_category->value()->nid,
    );
  }

  uasort($doors, 'rs_doors_natural_sort');

  return $doors;
}
```

it is getting thousands of nodes at time in a single page and it takes too much time to load.

So I think I need to paginate the query. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
$doors_nids = db_select('node', 'n')

->condition('n.type', 'vivarium_door')

->fields('n', array('nid'))

->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')

->extend('PagerDefault')->limit(10)

->execute()

->fetchCol();
```

Hopes this will helps you.

Comment: @Smalution- thanks for your response i will check with this and come back to you

Comment: @Smalution- it is showing like this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$doors_nids' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: can you see my edits ...after modification of code..my full code has shown above..

Comment: updated answer you can check now.

Comment: @ Smalution - thanks..i will check and get back to you

Comment: @ Smalution - still it is showing error..actually i am calling the doors with the combination of fee...in one place calling the function of doors and another function as fee and i will combine the both as one one function ...according to person wise have to select month and year the fee will show automatically it is working properly but having due to lot of data it is showing proxy server error so thats why need to do pagination ..can i share my . module file for you...pls help me on this it will very helpful for me....

Comment: @Smalution Please don't just show code; explain it and the difference with the code shown by the OP.

Comment: @DINE That is a completely different question. Users are answering about the code you are showing in the question. If you have another question about other code, please ask as new question.

Comment: @ kiamlaluno - thanks for your response ..i will post as new que

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong method: It's not `limit()`, but `range()` that you should use.

```
  $query = db_select('node', 'n')
    ->condition('n.type', 'vivarium_door')
    ->fields('n', array('nid'))
    ->orderBy('n.title', 'ASC')
    ->range(0, 10);

  $result = $query->execute(); // Add here the call to fetchCol().
```

Notice that dynamic queries are slower than static queries; you should use them when you want other modules to dynamically alter your query. In the other cases, you should use static queries (i.e. use `db_query()` or `db_query_range()`).

```
$query = db_query_range("SELECT n.nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = 'vivarium_door' ORDER BY n.title ASC", 0, 10);
```

#### Reference

- [Range and limit](https://www.drupal.org/node/1848368)
- [Dynamic queries](https://www.drupal.org/dynamic-queries) (It contains example code for using `range()`.)